# Google Earth Plugin performance

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We have several problems with Google Earth Plugin performance, particularly when we change the modes - from the one where we control moving object (aircraft) to the panoramic mode (where we just watch around, zoom etc). We believe this is due to the plug-in being forced to reload our and their own 3D images. The question is, if there is a way to improve that?

1. Is there a way to pre-load all 3D stuff in GE plug-in?
2. Is there an equivalent of Google Earth Pro for Google Earth plug-in - so we can get better performance with regard to loading 3D stuff?

Ideas will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Suggest including a link. This could well be caused by a programming issue. In general the plugin uses the same cache mechanism as standalone client, which works quite well.

Comment: We are using Google Earth Plugin - Version: 6.2.2.6613

Comment: I will try to get here a piece of the code. We observe delay of at least 2-3 sec when switching the modes and reloading the models.